# Scaled ModelMatrix messes with Diffuse lighting

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So, I have a hopefully simple question:

I have a simple cube, I'm useing `Matrix.ScaleM` to scale the modelview and compress the cube(There's a reason for this, trust me).

This work, the cube shrinks. However, my fragment shader no longer properly applies the diffuse light source to the top a bottom on the cube. The shade code is as follows.

```
precision mediump float;        
uniform vec3 u_LightPos;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture2;

varying vec3 v_Position;
varying vec4 v_Color;
varying vec3 v_Normal;          // Interpolated normal for this fragment.
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.

// The entry point for our fragment shader.
void main()                         
{                              

        float distance = length(u_LightPos - v_Position);

// Get a lighting direction vector from the light to the vertex.
vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - v_Position);                  

    // Calculate the dot product of the light vector and vertex normal. If the normal and light vector are
// pointing in the same direction then it will get max illumination.
float diffuse = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector), 0.0);                                                                                 
mediump float emptyness = 0.0;
mediump float half_emptyness = 0.1;
// Add attenuation. 
diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.10 * distance)));

// Add ambient lighting
diffuse = diffuse + 0.3;  
vec4 textColor1 = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);
vec4 textColor2 = texture2D(u_Texture2, v_TexCoordinate);



// Multiply the color by the diffuse illumination level and texture value to get final output color.


if(textColor2.w == emptyness){
    diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.10 * distance)));
    gl_FragColor = ( diffuse * textColor1 );//v_Color *

    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
} else{
    diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.75 * distance)));
    gl_FragColor = ( diffuse * textColor1 );//v_Color *
    gl_FragColor.a = 0.0;
}



}
```

So, any ideas?

And I know the color is a little...odd. That's for a completely different reason.

EDIT: As requested, the vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;

varying vec3 v_Position;        // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
varying vec4 v_Color;           // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
varying vec3 v_Normal;          // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

// The entry point for our vertex shader.
void main()
{
// Transform the vertex into eye space.
v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);

// Pass through the color.
v_Color = a_Color;

// Pass through the texture coordinate.
v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;

// Transform the normal's orientation into eye space.
v_Normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));
float halfer = 2.0;

// gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
// Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in normalized screen coordinates.
gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;

}
```

Comment: Can you post your vertex shader too?

Comment: Your normals should be multiplied with the inverse transpose of the model-view, not the model-view. Denormalizing normals will have very strange effects.

Comment: Here is your problem: v_Normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0)); Pass the inverse transposed and use it there as Andreas said. Also your normal is being scaled.

Comment: Okay, I can understand what your saying, but I have no way to render that into code. How would I do this? I'm not exactly the best when it comes to GLSL.

Comment: @rPaskiewicz: you may compute the inverse outside the shader and send it as a uniform

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an inverted transposed matrix like this:

Shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_IT_MVMatrix;
...
v_Normal = vec3(u_IT_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0));
```

In your Java code you create the matrix from your regular MV matrix like this:

```
invertM(tempMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);
transposeM(it_modelViewMatrix, 0, tempMatrix, 0);
```

Then you'll just need to pass this into the shader as a uniform.